# How to get bluetooth port indentifier from bluetooth printer

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-printing

I am working on one Bluetooth printing application, in which I discover all near by Bluetooth. Now I have to check particular Bluetooth is Samsung printer OR zebra printer or any other type of printer.

As we can get identifier of bluetooth by using ExternalAccessory.framework in iOS by using following code.

```
ExternalAccessory.framework
  if ([accessory.protocolStrings indexOfObject:@"com.zebra.rawport"] != NSNotFound) {
      discoveredPrinter.device_type = @(DeviceTypeZebra);
}
```

I  searched for same way in Android, but I come to know in android we can not achieve this kind of thing with Bluetooth. Please let me know if anyone resolved same issue before to identify type of Bluetooth printer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BluetoothClass.Device.Major](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device.Major) and [BluetoothClass.Device](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothClass.Device) to identify a type of device. For a printer, it would be:

```
if (btDevice.bluetoothClass.majorDeviceClass == BluetoothClass.Device.Major.IMAGING 
    && btDevice.bluetoothClass.deviceClass == 1664) 
{
    // it's a printer
```

From then on you can try Epson's [ESC codes](http://lprng.sourceforge.net/DISTRIB/RESOURCES/PPD/epson.htm) (the *de facto* standard) or the manufacturer's SDKs (like [Zebra](https://www.zebra.com/gb/en/products/software/barcode-printers/link-os/link-os-sdk.html)'s).

As for OUIs they're defined by [IEEE](http://standards-oui.ieee.org/oui/oui.txt) but you can get them in a more [sanitized](https://linuxnet.ca/ieee/oui/#nmap) form.

([Source](http://domoticx.com/bluetooth-class-of-device-lijst-cod/%3C) for the printer class code, in Dutch.)